# Defining the pins of Realtek TX2 IC

Tags: datasheet, encoder, pins

Can anyone explain clearly what is the purpose of SC and SO pins of [TX2](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FWW/CD13/GV525G0X/FWWCD13GV525G0X.pdf) encoder? Why SC isn't connected anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO is "encoded signal" (a series of pulses at low speed, 84Hz) and SC is "encoded signal modulated onto a carrier" (frequency in region of 100KHz, depending on other components).

There are two example circuits in that datasheet: 27MHz radio control, and 114KHz infrared control. The radio one uses external modulation, taking the encoded signal from SO and modulating it onto the RF carrier via a transistor. The infrared one lets the IC do the modulation before transmitting it through the LED directly.

Answer (score 0):

> **Can anyone explain clearly what is the purpose of SC and SO pins of TX2 encoder?**

The datasheet explains

> SC encoding signal with carrier frequecy
>   SO encoding signal without carrier frequency

so that should be clear enough?

> **Why SC isn't connected anywhere?**

In the diagram on page 8, SO is connected. This is a radio transmitter.

In the diagram at the top of page 12, SC is connected. This is an infrared transmitter.